# In hue notebook under sources hive is not showing up

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hue

Currently trying to run hue on top of helm chart provided in https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/hue/hue

However after spinning up only postgres showing up under sources section , how to show hive as source in the notebook section

[image]